# PHP: is it possible to call nesting object's method inside nested object?

Tags: php

I don't know how to explain this better, so (see comment inside second class):

```
<?php

    class main {
        public function something() {
            echo("do something");
        }
        public function something_else() {
            $child=new child();
            $child->child_function();
        }
    }

    class child {
        public function child_function() {
            echo("child function");
            //is it possible to call main->something() here somehow if this class is initiated inside class main?
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass `$this` (inside `main`) to the constructor of `child`. Be careful you don't end up with spaghetti, though!

Comment: Thanks deceze and Mihai, I've used your advice and it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Objects do not simply have access to stuff in a higher scope. You need to pass `main` into `child` explicitly:

```
$child->child_function($this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function `something_else` as public, so you can access that after creating object of main class.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    class main {
        public function something() {
            echo("do something");
        }
        public function something_else() {
            $child=new child($this);
            $child->child_function();
        }
    }

    class child {
        protected $_main;
        public function __construct($main)
        {$this->_main = $main;}
        public function child_function() {
            echo("child function");
             $this->_main->something();
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your child object with main.
This allows child to access the parent classes by calling *$this->something();* as it becomes a member of the main class, and gains access to all of it's properties and methods.

```
<?php    
    class main {
        public function something() {
            echo("do something");
        }
    }

    class child extends main {
        public function child_function() {
            echo("child function");
            //is it possible to call main->something() here somehow if this class is initiated inside class main?
            $this->something();
        }
    }

?>
```

if you want to __construct() in both you can do:

```
public function __construct () {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

This goes for all methods.